# Grouping different timeranges on hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am trying to perform a query that is quite resource efficient and give me the following results:

| id | period | clicks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 162 | 60d | 123 |
| 162 | 90d | 200 |
| 7162 | 60d | 127 |
| 7162 | 90d | 6718 |

For that I have so far, the following query:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    '90d' AS period,
    SUM(clicks) as clicks
FROM
    daily_performance
WHERE
    date BETWEEN date_sub(current_date(),90) AND current_date()
GROUP BY
    id
```

I was wondering if it is possible to add another grouping set that would only consider the past 60 days without having to query all partitions again. My final result should have both 60d/90d periods, and I would like to simplify my code by not having two different CTEs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily using case when or if and data duplication.
So, first you get base data using rs subquery - where you calculate 90d and 60d buckets.
Then, you generate two rows if data is both 90d and 60d and generate one row when only 90d.
Performance wise it should be better than CTE on same table but pls test it thoroughly.

```
SELECT id,
       CASE
           WHEN dummy=0 THEN p1
           WHEN dummy =1 THEN p2
           ELSE NULL
       END AS period,
       clicks
FROM
  (SELECT id,
          CASE
              WHEN `date` BETWEEN date_sub(current_date(), 90) AND current_date() THEN '90d'
          END p1,
          CASE
              WHEN `date` BETWEEN date_sub(current_date(), 60) AND current_date() THEN '60d'
          END p2,
          SUM(clicks) AS clicks
   FROM etl.t99
   WHERE `date` BETWEEN date_sub(current_date(), 90) AND current_date()
   GROUP BY CASE
                WHEN `date` BETWEEN date_sub(current_date(), 90) AND current_date() THEN '90d'
            END ,
            CASE
                WHEN `date` BETWEEN date_sub(current_date(), 60) AND current_date() THEN '60d'
            END ,
            id) rs,

  (SELECT 0 dummy
   UNION SELECT 1 dummy) dummy_table -- This will generate two dummy records

WHERE CASE
          WHEN p1 IS NOT NULL
               AND p2 IS NOT NULL
               AND dummy in (0,
                             1) THEN 1 -- This will generate 90d and 60d

          WHEN p1 IS NOT NULL
               AND p2 IS NULL
               AND dummy =0 THEN 1 -- This will generate only 90

          ELSE 0
      END = 1
```

Sample data and result in below images.
[image: Sample data]
[image: Result]